# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed using firebird

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

I have written a database application, developed it inside Windows 7, using Delphi XE2, using a firebird database. All worked well, when I start the server and the client either on one pc or the over a LAN all is well. So today I moved the server and client over to Windows Server 2008 R2, and this is where the problems started.

Firstly, I installed *Firebird 2.5*, and I start my server, it starts up. Then I try to start the client on the same pc as the server, and this is when I get the error :

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

I do not know where to start to solve this. It is the first time I use the Windows Server OS, so I do not know if it is OS related, as all worked fine when I run it on Windows 7.

EDIT: I'm using an TSQLConnection for the firebird, it's driver is set to datasnap, Port 211, hostname localhost.
      On reading up I see that there is some issues with the microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 provider, I'm using an     small database with the client that is an MS Access Database, and it is in the 2007-2013 format, could it be that this is the issue? For the MSAccess database, I use the TADOConnection and TADOTable components.

Comment: When you set up the database connection in the Delphi code, there is a server name or IP in the connection string - have you updated it to match the new server?

Comment: Yes, the host name is the same as the server, even if I change the host name to localhost, since it is running on the same pc as the firebird server, it still gives me that error

Comment: Please add more informations about the connection (ADO, dbxpress, FireDAC, ...) and the settings. I guess it is ADO (most hits if you google the error message). BTW google is a good starting point dealing with unknown error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem. It was never the firebird, or any dll's that was the cause of the error. It seems that the Microsoft Server 2008 R2 does not like the connection string of the TADOConnection, as I was using a MSAcess database 2007 version, and the provider was Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider. When I changed the database to 2003 MSAccess database and changed the provider to Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider the problem was gone and my application is running smoothly. I just wonder now, why the newer format and newer provider did not work in the Microsoft Server 2008 R2.

Comment: In your question you are talking about `TSQLConnection` (belongs to dbXpress) and here you talk about `TADOConnection` (belongs to ADO). Noone can give you a valid answer if you are telling wrong facts.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the datasnap libraries. The following link may help you:

[Deploying dbExpress Database Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications)

Take a look at the "dbExpress deployment with driver DLLs" section.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What dll he should deploy when using ODBC?

Comment: I cannot see that it is an dll issue, I have tested another firebird application on the server and it worked without any hickups, the only difference between the two applications was that on the test application, it used a temp database that was a MSAccess 2003 format and the application that is not working uses a temp database MSAcess 2007 format, so I want to say it might be the provider of the connection string on the MSAccess 2007 that is causing the problem

Comment: @SirRufo sorry, I don't have any experience with ODBC + Delphi. If you allow me to take a guess, you would need only to have installed the ODBC Firebird provider, and use the appropriate Delphi component to talk with the ODBC (which I don't know which is). This is what I do when I need to connect to a PostgreSQL from C#, with ODBC (legacy app, ADO.Net is no option).